# c# LINQ OrderBy, dynamic objects, and null values

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, expression

I'm attempting to generate a dynamic expression that can order a list of ExpandoObjects.  I don't know what will be in the expandoobjects (string, int, decimal, datetime, etc).

Unfortunately, it appears that if a null value is in the list when doing an orderby, an exception is thrown.  I could remove the null values from my collection prior to sorting with a Where method, but I want to keep the null rows in the results returned.

What I was trying to do was generate an If Else statement, something like:

```
x => x.Item["Key"] != null ? x.Item["Key] : defaultvaluefortype
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
if (type == typeof (ExpandoObject))
        {
            arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "x");
            expr = arg;  //Get type of T
            var first = (IDictionary<string, object>) source.First();
            //Match the case of the string to the correct key value.
            var propval =
                first.Keys.First(x => String.Equals(x, prop, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)); 
            var key = Expression.Constant(propval, typeof(string));
            ParameterExpression dictExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDictionary<string, object>));
            var indexer = dictExpr.Type.GetProperty("Item");
            var exprkeyed = Expression.Property(expr, indexer, key);
            //Generates x.Item["KeyString"] so I can access the object.
            expr = exprkeyed;
            var Null = Expression.Constant(null);
            expr = Expression.NotEqual(expr, Null);
            expr = Expression.Condition(expr, exprkeyed, Expression.Constant(false)); //what do I return as the else?
            type = typeof(Object);
            }
```

Unfortunately, if I try to set a default based on the key type, I get an exception that the return values from my if/else don't match (ie; one is system.object, one is system.datetime).  I believe the default value for object is null as well, so that's not the best.

Is there a way to do this without using a where statement to remove the null entries first?  Maybe something I could return on the else that's like a skip or a sortlow/high?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You would return a `Expression.Default(typeof(T))`.
In your code you change

```
expr = Expression.Condition(expr, exprkeyed, Expression.Default(typeof(T)));
```